# Problem in SQL join with the record containing maximum date

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables, [reservation] and [food-prices].

Table [reservation] has two rows:

```
    id  userId  foodId  date
     1     1      1     2023-02-08
     2     1      2     2023-03-14
```

Table [food-prices] has four rows:

```
id  foodId    date      price
 1     1    2023-01-24   25
 2     1    2023-03-05   30
 3     2    2023-01-24   25
 4     2    2023-03-05   30
```

I want to join these two tables in such a way that the result have the most recent price for each reservation. I wrote this query:

```
SELECT [reservation].[id]
                    ,[reservation].[userId]
                    ,[reservation].[foodId]
                    ,[reservation].[date]
                    ,[food-prices].date
                    ,[food-prices].price
FROM [food].[dbo].[reservation]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [food-prices]
ON [reservation].foodId = [food-prices].foodId
AND [reservation].date >= [food-prices].date
```

And it results:

```
id  userId  foodId  [reservation].[date]    [food-prices].date    price
1      1       1         2023-02-08              2023-01-24        25
2      1       2         2023-03-14              2023-01-24        25
2      1       2         2023-03-14              2023-03-05        30
```

While I want

```
id  userId  foodId  [reservation].[date]    [food-prices].date    price
1      1       1         2023-02-08              2023-01-24        25
2      1       2         2023-03-14              2023-03-05        30
```

as a result.
How should I write such a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ranking function to defined the latest row for each `foodid`. Then join the data.

```
CREATE TABLE reservation (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    userId INT NOT NULL,
    foodId INT NOT NULL,
    date DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE food_prices (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    foodId INT NOT NULL,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    price DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO reservation (id, userId, foodId, date)
VALUES (1, 1, 1, '2023-02-08'),
       (2, 1, 2, '2023-03-14');

INSERT INTO food_prices (id, foodId, date, price)
VALUES (1, 1, '2023-01-24', 25),
       (2, 1, '2023-03-05', 30),
       (3, 2, '2023-01-24', 25),
       (4, 2, '2023-03-05', 30);

SELECT *
FROM reservation R
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY foodId ORDER BY date DESC) AS RowID
    FROM food_prices
) F
    ON R.foodId = F.foodId
WHERE F.RowID = 1;
```

[image]

---

Try this then:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT R.*
          ,f.date as food_price_date
          ,f.price
          ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY R.id ORDER BY F.date DESC) AS RowID
    FROM reservation R
    LEFT JOIN food_prices F
        ON R.foodId = F.foodId
        AND R.date >= F.date
) DS
WHERE RowID = 1
```

[image]